# Copying the cell from One workbook to another workbook in excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Workbook 1 is the data from where i have to pick the value and workbook is the destination book in the respective cell

Workbook1

[image]

Workbook2

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can Try:

```
    Dim wb1 as workbook, wb2 as workbook    

    Set wb1 = workbooks("Workbook1")
    Set wb2 = workbooks("Workbook2")

    wb1.range("Cell to be copied").copy wb2.range("Cell where you want the data")
```

Comment: showing the error as method or data member not found in vba.                                                                                               :Sub foo1()

    Dim src As Workbooks
    Dim trg As Workbooks
    Dim LastRow As Long


    Set src = ThisWorkbook.Workbooks("Workbook1")
    Set trg = ThisWorkbook.Workbooks("Workbook2")


    src.Range("E2").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("A2")
    
    src.Range("E3").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("B2")

    src.Range("T8").Copy Destination:=trg.Range("F2")